# What are the benefits of using hard coded gas values in smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, gas, gas-limit, arbitrum

I was reading the docs of [Arbitrum](https://developer.offchainlabs.com/docs/security_considerations) and found this

> hard coded gas values should be adjusted (or better yet, removed entirely if possible (it's probably possible; really now, why are you hard-coding a gas value?))

I usually hard-code the gas (inside a smart contract) when I only transfer ether using my contract or in some other cases when I call another contract and I do that to prevent reentrancy attacks.

Are there any other reasons that I'm not aware of?